# Why my cloud function is not executing for all my entries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that will go throught every order in my orders category get the users which order is older than 1 day and send them a reminder notification, but for some reason when I execute this call sometimes the notification is sent and sometimes not, why is this happening ?

```
exports.sendReminder = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const messaging = admin.messaging();

    const tsToMillis = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis()
    const compareDate = new Date(tsToMillis - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    
    const snap = await db.collection('orders').where("timestamp","<",new Date(compareDate)).where("status", "in" ,[1,2,4,5,6]).get()
    let allPromises = [];

    if(snap.size > 0){
        snap.forEach((doc) => {
            const userId = doc.data().uid;

            allPromises.push(db.collection('user').doc(userId).get().then(userSnapshot => {
                const userData = userSnapshot.data();
                if (userData) {
                    const deviceToken = userData.deviceToken;
                    const payload = {
                        notification: {
                            title: "¿ Did you receive your order ?",
                            body: "We would love to know if you have received your order",
                            clickAction: "AppMainActivity"
                        },
                        data: {
                            ORDER_REMINDER: "ORDER_REMINDER"
                        }
                    }
                    res.status(200).send('Done!')
                    return messaging.sendToDevice(deviceToken,payload) 
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }));
        }); 
    }
    return Promise.all(allPromises);
});
```

Why is this function not correctly sending notifications ? I have encountered this problem with Firebase cloud functions before, it seems it does not handle properly the propagation of the notifications, I'm doing something wrong from my side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to delay sending the response until after all of the messages are finished sending, for the reason Michael mentioned. Take the `send()` out of the loop and make it the very last thing:

```
Promise.all(allPromises).then(() => {
  res.status(200).send('Done!')
  return null;
});
return null;
```

Comment: This should be at the finish of my function ? because it expects also says each then should return an exception or throw

Comment: You an add a return at the bottom of the promise callback if your lint tool requires it.  And it probably doesn't want you to "return an exception".

Comment: when we return that null in the promise it says that it finished all the work for each promise inside the Promise.all right ?

Comment: I got this error doug Error: could not handle the request

Comment: That sounds like a new and completely different problem.  Post a new question to explain what is now not working the way you expect.

Comment: Hmm this is weird, after executed this function 3 times the notifications are not arriving anymore, what could happend ?

Answer (score 2):

You are sending a response before sending the push notifications. As soon as you use `res.send()` in a Cloud Function the execution is considered complete and CPU/networking resources will be clamped down. You likely want this instead:

```
return messaging.sendToDevice(deviceToken,payload).then(() => {
  res.status(200).send('Done!')
});
```

Comment: Hi Michael, since this is not the last promise that I have executed it says that each then should return or throw an exception